# Visual C++ PrintDocument error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++-cli

I've called a printDocument action and a buttonClick event with this code:

```
private: System::Void btnPrint_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    PrintDialog prdl = gcnew PrintDialog();            
    printDialog1->Document = printDocument1;
    printDialog1->UseEXDialog = true;                 
    printDocument1->Print();
         }
```

I basically have a data grid view component, a print dialog component, a print document component, and a button. Upon button clicked I tried using that code to show me a printing dialog then attempt to print the table in the canter of the page, however I'm getting this error:

```
c:\documents and settings\stefan.mona-h6h4kpujnf\desktop\centralizator_debite\centralizator_debite\Form1.h(212): error C3673: 'System::Windows::Forms::PrintDialog' : class does not have a copy-constructor
```

I'm using Visual studio 2010 Windows forms application. I have every component I need (see above) and I'm clueless as to how I can solve this error.

Answer (score 3):

I have no clue what `gcnew` is, but if you intended to write

```
PrintDialog prdl = new PrintDialog();
```

try this instead

```
PrintDialog prdl();
```

The difference is that in the first case you create a object on the heap and try to initialize from the pointer.

**edit:** just googled that this is actually C++/CLI not pure C++

The reason why it isn't working is:
*no copy constructor* that means you can:

```
 mytype uniqueID() //build a unique id from scratch
```

but you can't

```
 mytype uniqueID = someOtherID; //create a unique id by copying.
```

Allso with my c++ background the use of `gcnew PrintDialog()` in the context is somewhat unclear to me, but my best guess is that it does the following:

1. Create Object on heap with automatic memory managment
2. returns a handle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI#Handles)

So maybe you want to try this aswell

```
PrintDialog^ prdl = gcnew PrintDialog();
```

The difference is as follows:

```
PrintDialog prdl();
```

creates a local variable, it will be gone once the context (function) is left

```
PrintDialog^ prdl = gcnew PrintDialog();
```

Creates an object on the heab manages by the garbage collection. This means you can actually do this

```
 PrintDialog^ get() { return gcnew PrintDialog; }

 main() {
    ...
    PrintDialog^ dialog = get();
    //use dialog
 }
```

With the first method the Dialog would be dead, the moment `get()` returned, while in the second case it will live till the garbagecollector runs and determines that it can't be accessed any more and thus deletes it to free memory.

Comment: using new gave me another error telling me to use gcnew instead.

Comment: `gcnew` is part of [Microsoft's C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI) language.